# Is there an alternative to getClass().getResource() for a Static ImageIcon

Tags: java, static, imageicon

Ok so I got a static ImageIcon and the Image just doesn't show up. In the same program I use other ImagesIcon but they are not static so when I declare them I do it like this:

```
public ImageIcon blabla = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(blabla.png));
```

But if I declare a ImageIcon Static I cannot use that line since one cannot get acces to getClass() from a static value. Right now those images are not showing up using this:

```
public static ImageIcon blabla = new ImageIcon(blabla.png);
```

Thanks for your help!

```
public static ImageIcon networkOfflineIcon = new ImageIcon("Images/networkOfflineIcon.png");
public static ImageIcon networkIcon = new ImageIcon("Images/networkIcon.png");
protected static JMenuItem jmiRemote = new JMenuItem("  Remote", networkOfflineIcon);
//************************************************************************
public static void changeNetWorkStatus(boolean network_status)          
//************************************************************************
{
    if(network_status){
        Application.jmiRemote.setIcon(networkIcon);
        Application.jmiRemote.setText("NetWork Online/Remote is On");
        Application.lockScreenRemote();

    }else if(!network_status){
        Application.jmiRemote.setIcon(networkOfflineIcon);
        Application.jmiRemote.setText("NetWork Offline/Remote is Off");
        Application.unlockScreenRemote();
    }
}//DOESNT CHANGE THE IMAGE
//************************************************************************
```

Comment: Try to avoid stuff like `if (t == true)` and `if (t == false)`, use `if (t)` and `if( ! t )` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a static context, you can write:

```
public ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(MyClass.class.getResource("icon.png"));
```

Or, alternatively try [`ImageIO.read(new File("icon.png"))`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read%28java.io.File%29)

Comment: Works fine now thank you for the fast fix i will also avoid (t == true)

Comment: `ImageIO.read` is not the best suggestion since you then need to handle the exceptions that it throws. I would stick with the first suggestion and use `MyClass.class`.